# How to add data to tableView even if the textfield is empty?

Tags: javafx, tableview, textfield

I'm trying to make a program which gets data from textfield, adds it to tableview and then to DB. The problem is, that I also need a tableview to accept an empty textfield value.

This is how I add values to the tableview:

```
 public void pievButtonClicked() {
    int kods = Integer.parseInt(kodsT.getText());
    String nosaukums = nosaukumsT.getText();
    int inventars = Integer.parseInt(iegadesT.getText());
    double uzskaite = Double.parseDouble(uzskaitesT.getText());
    double iegade = Double.parseDouble(iegadesT.getText());
    data.addAll(new Interjers(kods, nosaukums, inventars, uzskaite, iegade));
}
```

Maybe I need to change "Interijers" class or I need to change `setCellValueFactory` is some way. I really don't know.

Comment: What"s your stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do want exactly ! but i made this example for you ,it seems explain your need

Model class:

```
package javafxapplication4;


public class Model {

    String name;
    String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public Model(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="javafxapplication4.HomeController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@home.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="nameField" layoutY="30.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="ageField" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="30.0" />
      <Button layoutX="451.0" layoutY="30.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addLine" text="Button" />
      <TableView fx:id="view" layoutX="52.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="506.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameCo" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="ageCo" prefWidth="75.0" text="Age" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller class :

```
package javafxapplication4;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Ala_Eddine
 */
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @FXML
    public TableView<Model> view;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Model, String> nameCo;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Model, String> ageCo;

    @FXML
    public TextField nameField;

    @FXML
    public TextField ageField;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    nameCo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    ageCo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));
    }

    @FXML
    public void addLine() {
        String name = nameField.getText();
        String age = ageField.getText();
        Model model = new Model(name, age);
        view.getItems().add(model);

    }

}
```

Main class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication4;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Ala_Eddine
 */
public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Stage stage=new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Result 
[image]

Comment: The problem is that i'm getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` all the time when i'm trying to leave `textfield` empty. I could catch `NumberFormatException` and if it happens, just set value to null or something, but I will need to add it to DB also later so I don't think so this solution will work. Here is the links to my code: [main](https://pastebin.com/CdCrnGFT), [DataAccessor](https://pastebin.com/NwLeuNu0), [Product](https://pastebin.com/WqAvEjma). And here is the link to UI of program to see where i'm right now:[image](https://imgur.com/a/6U4T3).

Comment: Because you tried to parse empty value ,you need make a test for empty .